# Flatten n-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I worked out an algorithm that can be used recursively, which works in a non-recursive manner, however, I cannot test it in recursive form because I cannot create a n-1 dimensional variable from the template.
For help I write down the variable names and its meaning:

- `v`: the n-dimensional vector
- `dims`: n long vector with every dimension (e.g: if it was an array looking like `int x[3][6][4]`, then `dims` looks like: {3, 6, 4})
- `p`: product of the dimensions, used to get the size of the flat vector (e.g: 3*6*4)
- `ret`: the returned flat vector
- `sub_dims`: same as `dims` execpt without the first dimension (e.g: {6, 4})
- `sub_p`: same as `p` except without the first factor (e.g: 6*4)
- `sub_ret`: the returned flat vector for the n-1 dimensional vector

the code:

```
template <typename T>
vector<int> dim_flat(vector<T> v, vector<int> dims)
{
    // creating variables and vectors
    int n = dims.size();
    int p = dims[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        p *= dims[i];
    }
    int sub_p = p / dims[0];
    vector<int> sub_dims;
    sub_dims.assign(dims.begin() + 1, dims.end());
    vector<int> ret(p);

    // algorithm
    if (n > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dims[0]; i++)
        {
            vector<int> sub_ret = dim_flat(v[i], sub_dims);

            for (int j = 0; j < sub_p; j++)
            {
                ret[i * sub_p + j] = sub_ret[j];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // case for the input is 1D 
        // not yet written
    }

    return ret;
}
```

With this code the project build, however if I call it in main:

```
vector<int> ret = dim_flat(v, dims);
```

where `v` is e.g. an 4D vector and `dims` is a vector containing {3, 3, 3, 3}, then I get the following when trying to build:

```
error C2784: 'std::vector<_Ty> dim_flat(std::vector<T>,std::vector<_Ty>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::vector<T>' from 'int'
```

for the line

```
vector<int> sub_ret = dim_flat(v[i], sub_dims);
```

I kinda (but not really) understand the meaning of this error, so I expected the same to happen, which it did for this:

```
T x = v[i];
vector<int> sub_ret = dim_flat(x, sub_dims);
```

This is the part where I don't really understand the error anymore, because I thought that with the argument `vector<T> v` I specified that the input e.g. 4D vector will be understood as a vector of `T` where `T` is a 3D vector that can be also indexed since its a `vector<T>`. So following this logic I thought that if I give the recursion the first `T` being a 3D vector, then a step deeper this 3D vector will now be understood as a vector of `T'` where `T'` is a 2D vector, and so on.

Clearly either my logic is flawed, or I used the wrong method (, or both), so the question is: How can I solve / fix this?

EDIT:
Credit to Max66 for the solution.
The code probably could be more optimized, but at least now it works.
Code:

```
//// for integer only
// case input is 0-dimensional (simply a variable)
template <typename T>
vector<int> dim_flat (const T &v, const vector<int> &dims)
{
    return vector<int>(1, v);
}

// case input is n-dimensional
template <typename T>
vector<int> dim_flat(const vector<T> &v, const vector<int> &dims)
{
    // creating variables and vectors
    int n = dims.size();
    int p = dims[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        p *= dims[i];
    }
    int sub_p = p / dims[0];
    vector<int> sub_dims;
    sub_dims.assign(dims.begin() + 1, dims.end());
    vector<int> ret(p);

    // algorithm
    if (n > 1) // case n-dimensional
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dims[0]; i++)
        {
            vector<int> sub_ret = dim_flat(v[i], sub_dims);
            for (int j = 0; j < sub_p; j++)
            {
                ret[i * sub_p + j] = sub_ret[j];
            }
        }
    }
    else // case 1-dimensional
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            vector<int> sub_ret = dim_flat(v[i], sub_dims);
            ret[i] = sub_ret[0];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: add the function

```
std::vector<int> dim_flat (int v, std::vector<int> const &)
 { return {v}; }
```

if you can use C++11 or newer, or

```
std::vector<int> dim_flat (int v, std::vector<int> const &)
 { return std::vector<int>(1, v); }
```

if you have to use C++98

Long answer: if I'm not wrong, the problem is that, when you call `dim_flat()` with an `std::vector<int>` (when `T` is `int`), you have `n == 1`, so `dim_flat()` isn't called (is executed the "case for the input 1D") **but** the compiler isn't so smart to understand that there is no need to call `dim_flat()` with `int` (instead `std::vector<T>`) so look for `dim_flat(int, std::vector<int>)` and doesn't find it.

So, to make the compiler happy, you have to implement  `dim_flat(int, std::vector<int>)`.

Can be a dummy function (that return an empty vector), but I suggest you to implement it correctly.

A little of topic: please, avoid unusefull copies of vectors; in your `dim_flat()`, `v` and `dims` are only readed, not modified; so you can receive they as const reference, as follows

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<int> dim_flat(std::vector<T> const   &  v,
                          std::vector<int> const &  dims)
```

P.s.: why don't you simply write as follows ?

```
std::vector<int> dim_flat (std::vector<int> const & v)
 { return v; }

template <typename T>
std::vector<int> dim_flat(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const & v)
 {
   std::vector<int>  ret;

   for ( auto const & e : v )
    {
      auto s = dim_flat(e);

      ret.reserve( ret.size() + s.size() );
      ret.insert( ret.end(), s.cbegin(), s.cend() );
    }

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! With a minimal adjustment (instead of `int v` I had to use `T v`), it works. For some reason the C++11 format for returning didn't work and I got `syntax error`, but the C++98 format works. Also thank you for the suggestion on the const reference. Even though I knew about it, and actually wanted to use it, but I still somehow forgot to put there.